# Spark: writing dataframe to parquet raise error

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, parquet

Here is my code:

```
 df.write
          .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .parquet("d:/filename/sample.parquet")
```

It creates 0KB parquet file.

Please help. What might be the error? 
I wrote this code on IntelliJ IDEA and facing an issue to write the dataframe parquet.

I need my dataframe to be In parquet format, but its giving me 0Kb parquet file. Its empty

Here is my error:

```
ERROR Utils: Aborting task
ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:859)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:842)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have the directory `d:/filename` available? Do you have write permissions to the directory? Change `d:/filename/sample.parquet` to `d:/output` and start over. You should specify a directory (for parquet files) not a single parquet file to write to.

Comment: I do have write permission for the directory,  it creates a folder structure like this d:\filename\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20171031165322_0000_m_000000_0\part-00000-5d8060ef-6c34-4d31-89b6-431d8fd5dac8-c000.snappy.parquet

Comment: Curiously, it seems Spark is trying to write a CSV file - since the `CSVOutputWriter` is called. Did the code above lead to this stack trace?

Comment: yes it did lead to above stack trace

Comment: This issue is resolved, I had to set hadoop_home variables properly.